# How to check if the clicked element is before or after the current active element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a list item, the first one already have `.active` class.

When I click to other list item, the `.active` class move to that clicked element.

But the problem is, I can't detect if item that I clicked before or after the previous `.active` element.

Here's the script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $li = $("li");

  $li.each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
      $li.removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      
      if($("li.active").next($(this))){
        $("span").text("after clicked element");
      } else {
        $("span").text("before clicked element");
      }
    })
  })
})
```

```css
li.active {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">Check 1</li>
  <li>Check 2</li>
  <li>Check 3</li>
  <li>Check 4</li>
</ul>

<span></span>
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gds80k3q/)

Comment: What about just saving the id, child index or any other identifier of the active element so you don't have to loop over all the list items every time, since you'll both know the current active one and the one just clicked. (And hence, will be able to compare indexes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can check the `index()` of the relevant elements in your `if` statement. Also note that the `each()` statement is redundant. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").click(function() {
    var activeIndex = $('li.active').removeClass('active').index();
    var thisIndex = $(this).addClass('active').index();

    if (activeIndex < thisIndex) {
      $("span").text("after active element");
    } else if (activeIndex > thisIndex) {
      $("span").text("before active element");
    } else {
      $('span').text('same element');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
li.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">Check 1</li>
  <li>Check 2</li>
  <li>Check 3</li>
  <li>Check 4</li>
</ul>

<span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with index if understand you correctly this will solve issue:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $li = $("li");
  $li.each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      if ($("li.active").index()<$(this).index()) {
        $("span").text("after clicked element");
      } else {
        $("span").text("before clicked element");
      }
      $li.removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    })
  })
})
```

```css
li.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">Check 1</li>
  <li>Check 2</li>
  <li>Check 3</li>
  <li>Check 4</li>
</ul>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the `index` of recently clicked element and compare it with the previous one.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var index = 0;
    $('li').click(function(){
      $('li').removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active"); 
      var res = $("li.active").index() > index ? 'after' : $("li.active").index() == index ? 'same' : 'before';
      index = $(this).index();
      console.log(res);
    })
  })
```

```css
li.active {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">Check 1</li>
  <li>Check 2</li>
  <li>Check 3</li>
  <li>Check 4</li>
</ul>

<span></span>
```